# LogFile Reverse with C# Array - Empty row

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have this 3-liner to reverse my saved logfile fast:

```
string[] lines = LogText.Text.Split('\n');
Array.Reverse(lines);
LogText.Text = String.Join("\n", lines);
```

Sadly it's like "TEXT\nTEXT\nTEXT\n" So after a Reverse I have "\nTEXT\nTEXT\nTEXT".

What is the best way to remove this line?
Simply cut the first char after the reverse? Is this really elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last '\n' is being recognized as a token. If you specify the RemoveEmptyEntries flag in string.Split, the problem will go away.

```
var text = "TEXT1\nTEXT2\nTEXT3\n";

string[] lines = text.Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Array.Reverse(lines);
text = String.Join("\n", lines);

Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Obviously this will only work well if you don't expect empty log lines. If you do, you could add logic to remove '\n' at the start or end of the array as desired.